# ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types

Tags: react-native

I am getting this warning in log :

> ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to
> ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types

even I haven't used `ViewPropTypes` anywhere in my code.

some of my packages are :

```json
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.2",
"native-base": "^2.13.14",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.4",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
"react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
```

Comment: Read here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33557#issuecomment-1093083115. This will make you clear about ViewPropTypes.

Comment: Part of my code with this warning was the Modal. Verify!

Comment: This [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated-carousel) completely solves this [problem](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/632) for react-native-snap-carousel!

Answer (score 115):

## Solution:

1. Install [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) into your project, as per the instructions.
2. Install deprecated-react-native-prop-types by running `npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types` or `yarn add deprecated-react-native-prop-types`.
3. The invariant seems to be enforced in `node_modules/react-native/index.js`, starting at line 436:

[image]

here is my patch file `react-native+0.69.3.patch`

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/React-bridging.podspec b/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/React-bridging.podspec
index 5255c13..52a8eb0 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/React-bridging.podspec
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/React-bridging.podspec
@@ -30,7 +30,7 @@ Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   s.source                 = source
   s.source_files           = "react/bridging/**/*.{cpp,h}"
   s.exclude_files          = "react/bridging/tests"
-  s.header_dir             = "react/bridging"
+  s.header_dir             = "."
   s.header_mappings_dir    = "."
   s.compiler_flags         = folly_compiler_flags
   s.pod_target_xcconfig    = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/RCT-Folly\"",
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/index.js b/node_modules/react-native/index.js
index d59ba34..349b4dd 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/index.js
@@ -435,32 +435,16 @@ module.exports = {
   },
   // Deprecated Prop Types
   get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'ColorPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "ColorPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType
   },
   get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'EdgeInsetsPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "EdgeInsetsPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType
   },
   get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'PointPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "PointPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType
   },
   get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
-    invariant(
-      false,
-      'ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
-        "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
-    );
+    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes
   },
 };
```

So, change these lines to return the corresponding Prop Types from deprecated-react-native-prop-types instead:

[image]

4. Save and run `npx patch-package react-native` to save the patch.
5. Rebuild and the app should launch.

Only thing to keep in mind is that this patch will need to be reapplied with every upgrade to react-native, or until the libraries in question are updated to import from deprecated-react-native-prop-types instead.

Comment: much thanks, this fix the deprecation issues!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it is too weird that we have to make these changes manully.

Comment: Sad state of react-native, endless trail of issues that one has to solve themselves

Comment: Works perfect, but these fixes should be updated by default

Comment: After applying above changes : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentActQueue$1.isBatchingLegacy')

Comment: This is not right solution. The correct solution is to find third party library that still uses deprecated prop types. Please try to identify the problem and not just hide it )

Answer (score 72):

This is the patch issue and can be resolved by just replacing few lines of code:

1. check if you have installed **deprecated-react-native-prop-types** package if not run the below command first.

   yarn add deprecated-react-native-prop-types
2. inside **node_modules/react-native/index.js**

replace these functions with the below lines

```
// Deprecated Prop Types
get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType;
},

get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType;
},

get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType;
},

get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
},
```

Comment: If I refresh the modules by removing the "lock" it seems that these changes are lost. I thought that module prevented this. If I work on a shared repository, I assume each person has to go to that file and make changes, right?

Comment: For my version react-native: 0.72.3 this code was already added I just removed the `console.error` section code it removes the error. But why the error shows at the first place? I think I am using a package that used deprecated PropType. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 25):

#### Temporary solution.

***ignoreWarnings.js***

```js
import { LogBox } from "react-native";

if (__DEV__) {
  const ignoreWarns = [
    "EventEmitter.removeListener",
    "[fuego-swr-keys-from-collection-path]",
    "Setting a timer for a long period of time",
    "ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native",
    "AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native",
    "exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
    "Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state.",
    "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews",
  ];

  const warn = console.warn;
  console.warn = (...arg) => {
    for (const warning of ignoreWarns) {
      if (arg[0].startsWith(warning)) {
        return;
      }
    }
    warn(...arg);
  };

  LogBox.ignoreLogs(ignoreWarns);
}
```

***App.js***

```js
// import at the very top of everything.
import "../ignoreWarnings";
```

Comment: As of expo-sdk-47, this won't work since this is now an error, not warning.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using a version higher than the `react-native` `0.71.0`

> node_modules/react-native/index.js

**STEP1**

- Corresponding Line Annotation Process

```
 get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    // console.error(
    //   'ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all ' +
    //     'other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes ' +
    //     'and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to ' +
    //     'continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the ' +
    //     "'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.",
    // );
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
  },
```

**STEP2**

- Run patch-package for react-native

```
npx patch-package react-native
```

> You must run the following to prevent console errors at runtime

Comment: Errors are gone but still flash back

Answer (score 11):

in my case, the error came from `react-native-snap-carousel` library so here is how I fixed it in just 6 steps:

**Step 1**: `npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types` or `yarn add deprecated-react-native-prop-types`.

**Step 2**: open all of these 4 files which is exists in the directories

```js
node_modules\react-native-snap-carousel\src\carousel\Carousel.js
```

and

```js
node_modules\react-native-snap-carousel\src\pagination\Pagination.js
```

and

```js
node_modules\react-native-snap-carousel\src\pagination\PaginationDot.js
```

and

```js
node_modules\react-native-snap-carousel\src\parallaximage\ParallaxImage.js
```

**Step 3**: delete all `ViewPropTypes` which is imported from `react-native` and import it from `deprecated-react-native-prop-types` which is the module we installed at the **Step 1**, and put it in a separated line like this

```js
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'
```

**Step 4**: add this line `"postinstall": "patch-package",` in `package.json` in `scripts` section. example:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
```

**Step 5**: run this command `npx patch-package react-native-snap-carousel`.

**Step 6**: run this command `npm run postinstall`

Comment: I am on "react-native": "0.72.3", the issue was introduced by one of the dependencies, and this method works for me:))

Comment: same issue with snap-carousel. Worked now!

Answer (score 6):

Here you go , i gave some extra in case you are using Expo 45 new `gesture-handler 2.2` and `NativeBase` , the below removes the errors from `ViewPropTypes` and `react-native-gesture-handler` both from `LogBox` and `console`:

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native'
import ignoreWarnings from 'ignore-warnings';

ignoreWarnings('warn',['ViewPropTypes','[react-native-gesture-handler]'])

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
    'ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from \'deprecated-react-native-prop-types\'.',
    'NativeBase: The contrast ratio of',
    "[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you\'re using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!",
])
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just burnt out with this but getting "Could not find a declaration file for module 'ignore-warnings'." after `npm install --save ignore-warnings`.

Comment: Also, even with `import { LogBox } from "react-native"` and `LogBox.ignoreAllLogs()` at the top of App.js (and about every other page) I'm still getting pounded with the ViewPropTypes and other Expo 45 warnings. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Cory Using that code i am just getting one time the warning on the console and that's it . No more warnings . Have you tried `expo start -c` ?

Comment: I can confirm this is working but lines 2 and 4 are unnecessary and can be deleted in my case.

Answer (score 6):

**Got the solution !!!**

first of all install the package :

```
npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```

So when you check the call stack of the warning:

[image: ViewPropTypes error call stack]

You can find where the `ViewPropTypes error` is from.
In my case its in the `MultiSelect`.
So you go in the file (you can click on it)
otherwise it's in `node_module/react-native-multi-select/lib/react-native-multi-select.js`
And you remove `ViewPropTypes` from the import of `react-native`
and you add it from `deprecated-react-native-prop-types`
So the code was :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  UIManager,
  ViewPropTypes
} from 'react-native';
```

and it has to be :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  UIManager
} from 'react-native';
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'
```

Save and restart all the app.

**/!\ Watch out** if the warn is still there, it can be from another file, check the call stack again, do the same process. I had to do it also for the react-native-camera (RNCamera.js)

Answer (score 5):

Recently I faced this issue in my two react native projects. These steps works for me 100%. I didn't get any deprecated props error, After i fixed the issue.

testing module resolver usage to fix deprecated issue in react-native based on discussion in related react-native issue [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33557)

**Step 1**

Install the plugin

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```

or

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```

**Step 2**

create index.js file inside project folder `resolver/react-native/` with following code

```
import * as StandardModule from 'react-native';

const deprecatedProps = {
  ImagePropTypes: require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedImagePropType'),
  TextPropTypes: require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedTextPropTypes'),
  ViewPropTypes: require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedViewPropTypes'),
  ColorPropType: require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedColorPropType'),
  EdgeInsetsPropType: require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedEdgeInsetsPropType'),
  PointPropType: require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedPointPropType'),
};


// Had to use a proxy because ...StandardModule made think react-native that all modules were
// being used and was triggering some unnecessary validations / native dep checks.
// This prevents that from happening.
const objProx = new Proxy(StandardModule, {
  get(obj, prop) {
    if (prop in deprecatedProps) {
      return deprecatedProps[prop];
    }
    if (prop === 'Image') {

      return new Proxy(obj[prop], {
        get(obj, prop) {
          if (prop === 'propTypes') return deprecatedProps.ImagePropTypes;
          return Reflect.get(...arguments);
        },
      });;
    }
    if (prop === 'Text') {

      return new Proxy(obj[prop], {
        get(obj, prop) {
          if (prop === 'propTypes') return deprecatedProps.TextPropTypes;
          return Reflect.get(...arguments);
        },
      });
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  },
});

module.exports = objProx;
```

**Step 3**

configure module resolver inside `babel.config.js`, depends on your project requirement to blacklist/whitelist certain npm packages to prevent conflicting file.

example `module-resolver` config :

```
var path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      plugins: [
        ["module-resolver", {
          "root": ["."],
          resolvePath(sourcePath, currentFile, opts) {
            if (
              sourcePath === 'react-native' &&
              !(
                (
                  currentFile.includes('node_modules/react-native/') || // macos/linux paths
                  currentFile.includes('node_modules\\react-native\\')
                ) // windows path
              ) &&
              !(
                currentFile.includes('resolver/react-native/') ||
                currentFile.includes('resolver\\react-native\\')
              )
            ) {
              return path.resolve(__dirname, 'resolver/react-native');
            }
            /**
             * The `opts` argument is the options object that is passed through the Babel config.
             * opts = {
             *   extensions: [".js"],
             *   resolvePath: ...,
             * }
             */
            return undefined;
          }
        }],
     
      ],
    };
```

**Step 4**

You're using expo, should run this command

```
expo r -c
```

You're using React Native, should run this command

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same error and was lucky to resolve it within a short time.
In my case, I followed the following steps:

1. Install the patch-package by going to this website.

   https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package
2. Install deprecated-react-native-prop-types –

   ```
   npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types
   ```

   OR

   ```
   yarn add deprecated-react-native-prop-types
   ```
3. Go to node_modules/react-native/index.js and change this starting from:

   ```
    // Deprecated Prop Types
    get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
      invariant(
        false,
        "ColorPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
          "ColorPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
     );
    },
    get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
      invariant(
        false,
        "EdgeInsetsPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
          "EdgeInsetsPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
      );
    },
    get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
      invariant(
        false,
        "PointPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
         "PointPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
     );
    },
    get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
     invariant(
       false,
       "ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
         "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
     );
    },
   ```

**With this:**

```
  // Deprecated Prop Types
  get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ColorPropType
  },
  get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").EdgeInsetsPropType
  },
  get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").PointPropType
  },
  get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ViewPropTypes
  },
```

4. Save patch by running this command

   ```
   npx patch-package react-native
   ```
5. Rebuild App

   Note: If you upgrade react-native, you will need to reapply this patch.

Answer (score 4):

**Hi, devs**

*So, edit node_modules is not good way to resolve the problem*

I am using React Native with Expo CLI (RN 0.70.5, EXPO 47.0.6)

Follow step by step and be happy!

---

***LETS GO!!***

**STEP 1:**

- run command `yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver deprecated-react-native-prop-types`

**STEP 2:**

- in your root project create folder `resolver`, inside this create another folder `react-native`, inside this create `index.js` file.
  *looks like: `./resolver/react-native/index.js`*
- open the file and paste this:

```
import * as StandardModule from "react-native";

const deprecatedProps = {
  ImagePropTypes: require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedImagePropType"),
  TextPropTypes: require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedTextPropTypes"),
  ViewPropTypes: require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedViewPropTypes"),
  ColorPropType: require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedColorPropType"),
  EdgeInsetsPropType: require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedEdgeInsetsPropType"),
  PointPropType: require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedPointPropType"),
};

const imgProx = new Proxy(StandardModule.Image, {
  get(_, prop) {
    if (prop === "propTypes") return deprecatedProps.ImagePropTypes;
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  },
});

const txtProx = new Proxy(StandardModule.Text, {
  get(_, prop) {
    if (prop === "propTypes") return deprecatedProps.TextPropTypes;
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  },
});

const objProx = new Proxy(StandardModule, {
  get(_, prop) {
    if (prop in deprecatedProps) {
      return deprecatedProps[prop];
    }
    if (prop === "Image") {
      return imgProx;
    }
    if (prop === "Text") {
      return txtProx;
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  },
});

module.exports = objProx;
```

**STEP 3:**

- Edit `babel.config.js` file:
- add in `presets` array: `"module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"`.
- add in `plugins` array:

```
       "module-resolver",
       {
         root: ["."],
         resolvePath(sourcePath, currentFile) {
           if (
             sourcePath === "react-native" &&
             !(
               (
                 currentFile.includes("node_modules/react-native/") || // macos/linux paths
                 currentFile.includes("node_modules\\react-native\\")
               ) // windows path
             ) &&
             !(
               currentFile.includes("resolver/react-native/") ||
               currentFile.includes("resolver\\react-native\\")
             )
           ) {
             return path.resolve(__dirname, "resolver/react-native");
           }
           return undefined;
         },
       },
     ]
```

**STEP 4:**
run `expo r -c`

---

**CONGRATULATIONS, YOU ARE WELCOME**

Comment: error: node_modules/expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent.js: /Users/***/Documents/***/node_modules/expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent.js: path is not defined error.

Answer (score 4):

1- install "deprecated-react-native-prop-types" with npm

"npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types"

2-Then open react-native folder inside node_modules , There you will have index.js

3-Below comment note "// Deprecated Prop Types" you will see functions like this :

```
// Deprecated Prop Types
get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
invariant(
false,
"ColorPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
  "ColorPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
);
},

get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
invariant(
false,
"EdgeInsetsPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
  "EdgeInsetsPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop- 
types'.",
);
},
get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
invariant(
false,
"PointPropType has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
 "PointPropType exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
);
},
get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
invariant(
false,
"ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to " +
 "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
);
},
```

Replace it with code below :

```
get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ColorPropType
},

get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").EdgeInsetsPropType
},
get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").PointPropType
},
get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ViewPropTypes
},
```

Then save file and rebuild your project and run

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for them to update the dependencies or update the imports manually or even better make a pull request to help the community.

Comment: Won't help if the maintainers are nowhere to be found!

Answer (score 2):

**1) First run the following command in our project directory

```
 $ npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```

2. Then open the node modules, open the folder that u have installed before the
   error occuired

   in that folder index.js and remove the viewproptype in the file
   then import the following

   $ import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';**

Comment: Found out because of you, but its not really well explained. I made a proper answer down there

Answer (score 2):

If someone faces this issue,
I just solve it simply

***ERROR  ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.***

**then replace**

```
// Deprecated Prop Types
  get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    console.error(
      'ColorPropType will be removed from React Native, along with all ' +
        'other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes ' +
        'and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to ' +
        'continue using ColorPropType, migrate to the ' +
        "'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.",
    );
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType;
  },
  get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    console.error(
      'EdgeInsetsPropType will be removed from React Native, along with all ' +
        'other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes ' +
        'and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to ' +
        'continue using EdgeInsetsPropType, migrate to the ' +
        "'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.",
    );
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType;
  },
  get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    console.error(
      'PointPropType will be removed from React Native, along with all ' +
        'other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes ' +
        'and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to ' +
        'continue using PointPropType, migrate to the ' +
        "'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.",
    );
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType;
  },
  get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    console.error(
      'ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all ' +
        'other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes ' +
        'and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to ' +
        'continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the ' +
        "'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.",
    );
    return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
  },
```

***the code on node_modules/react-native/index.js line No 413 by***

```
// Deprecated Prop Types
get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ColorPropType;
},
get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").EdgeInsetsPropType;
},
get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").PointPropType;
},
get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
  return require("deprecated-react-native-prop-types").ViewPropTypes;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be in one of your packages, consider upgrading them to the latest version. I faced this issue after downgrading native-base to v2.15.2 from v3++. Moving back to version 3 did it for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32237076)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the react-native-camera plugin. If you don`t want to migrate to the latest plugin suggested. Must do the next steps:

The course of my solution, I went to the node-modules folder -> the react-native-camera folder and found the main file RNCamera.js
find ViewPropTypes import

```
import {
 findNodeHandle,
 Platform,
 NativeModules,
 requireNativeComponent,
 View,
 ViewPropTypes,
 ActivityIndicator,
 Text,
 StyleSheet,
 PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

//delete import this file from 'react-native' and create new import
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

and its work good.

Of course install the new plugin:

```
npm i deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```

And edit the index.js of the folder node_module/react-native.
Replace these functions with the below lines

```
// Deprecated Prop Types
get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType;
},

get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType;
},

get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType;
},

get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
},
```

Comment: My RN version is 0.70 and when I added these lines, it shows me different error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style')

Comment: I instead started having error ```Cannot read property 'source' of undefined```

Answer (score 1):

1. I resolved it by running:

   ```
   npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types
   ```
2. By importing `import {ViewPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'`,
   wherever it is required in the node dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are not using `ViewPropTypes` in your codebase directly some of the packages may be using it.

You can update all the packages that are using `ViewPropTypes` to a newer version.

1. Do a search for `ViewPropTypes` in your `node_modules` folder.
2. Update all packages using `ViewPropTypes` to newer versions.
3. `npx pod-install`(for iOS)
4. Restart the bundler
5. Refresh your app

Comment: This is probably the best answer because it doesn't include using deprecated packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy this code to the highest level code before App.

```
const ignoreWarns = [
    "Setting a timer for a long period of time",
    "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation",
    "ViewPropTypes will be removed",
    "AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native",
    "EventEmitter.removeListener",
];
const warn = console.warn;
console.warn = (...arg) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < ignoreWarns.length; i++) {
        if (arg[0].startsWith(ignoreWarns[i])) return;
    }
    warn(...arg);
};

LogBox.ignoreLogs(ignoreWarns);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this error when I install npm react-native-switch-pro ,but after much research I decide to uninstall it and I found it is the problem ,please if you install it try to uninstall it maybe it's the problem

Answer (score 0):

just open the RNCamera file from the node modules and comment the import and where viewproptype is used... and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Today I was working on this problem and I fixed it like this:

- Went to `node_modules`
- Then to `react-native-camera` library
- Then to the `src` folder inside `react-native-camera`
- Then to `RNCamera.js` file
- There I deleted `ViewPropTypes` imported from 'react-native' and in a new line wrote:

```js
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

Hope it works for you too!

Comment: This hack only works on your local machine and will fail if you or a team mate reinstall the project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause to remove deprecated type, hope this help someone:

1. Open yarn.lock (or package-lock.json), find "deprecated-react-native-prop-types"
2. Check which dependency using "deprecated-react-native-prop-types"
3. Update it to latest version

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install deprecated-react-native-prop-types:

`npm i deprecated-react-native-prop-types`.

Then, after that, find where the error is on the terminal and click its link to find where the `ViewPropTypes` was imported. Remove it and import it on its own like this:

```
import {ViewPropTypes} from "deprecated-react-native-prop-types"
```

Answer (score 0):

first, install npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types .

for my project I don't use this directly, but when I search in node_modules/ it appears in some of the libraries I use.

So the only solution is for those libraries to be updated.

for example, I had this error from react-native-snap-carousel. so, go to node_modules->react-native-snap-carousel->src->carousel.js

seems like a simple fix. but the work seems to fall on the libraries changing the import, instead of the react-native library.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'react-native'
```

with this

```
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'
```

Will fix the issue.

Answer (score -3):

I solved it opening a **node_modules** with vscode and serching for all "ViewPropTypes" that is inside 'react-native' module and replace it for:

```
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

Before:

```
import { Platform, ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native'
```

After:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import {ViewPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types';
```

Comment: I don't know what the right solution is, but this is very not it

Comment: @GlennMaynard I absolutely agree.

Comment: Also agreed. It's really up to the package authors to get rid of this warning for us. If you really wanted to follow this approach, you should at least use `patch-package`. As a band-aid for the annoyance, you can add the following to your App.jsx or similar top-level: `LogBox.ignoreLogs(["ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'."]);`

Comment: This is just a warning. You should be able to just ignore it.

Comment: @arrakis90 It doesn't go away even with `LogBox.ignoreLogs(["ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'."]);`

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS It may just depend on where you have the `ignoreLogs` if the warning happens before that line is called. In mine, I placed the ignore at the highest component I could which for me was `App.js`. You could also temporarily try `LogBox.ignoreAllLogs()` to see if it at least stops there.

Comment: @arrakis90 Finally i found out how to completely remove from the console too  , posted mt answer here :
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33557#issuecomment-1119774612

Comment: it's better to ignore the warning than following this solution

Comment: In the latest update it is no longer a warning but an error. So, this is the right solution for now.

Comment: @Abrar is correct, in react-native > 69 this causes a crash error.  This is the best solution.  I recommend using patch-package to manually patch the package, this allows you to maintain upgradability until the author publishes an update.