# WARN ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, native-base

Expo version: 45
Using Stack Navigation and Native Base.
I am using props but I am getting this warning.
Why I am getting this warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Native Base hasn't update their source code to include the migration to `deprecated-react-native-prop-types`. You can read more about it here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33557

You can add the following snippet at the start of your app (probably App.js) to suppress the warning for now.

```
import {LogBox} from "react-native";

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
"ViewPropTypes will be removed",
"ColorPropType will be removed",
])
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal is not to suppress, but its to solve it, follow the steps of the post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73313120/8119333