# Updated 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view' react native library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

So I'm currently making an app right now based out of react native and I'm trying to use the 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scrollable-tab-view) RN library. It had been working previously but when I upgraded my react from 16 to 18, the ViewPropTypes (that the library was using) has been deprecated. Now, I could just downgrade my react but I was wondering if there's any other way that could somehow help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702392/viewproptypes-will-be-removed-from-react-native-migrate-to-viewproptypes-export)

Answer (score 0):

Try to import ViewPropsTypes from deprecated-react-native-prop-types.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. To which file should I import this?

Comment: Search this problem in this library's GitHub issues to find out solution.