# React-Native Upgrade Issue: ERROR - ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase, lottie-react-native

I've recently upgraded my React-Native application from react-native@0.62.2 to 0.71.0. Following this upgrade, I've encountered an error when attempting to run my application:

**`ERROR: ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.`**

Upon inspecting my code, I didn't find any instances where I directly used **ViewPropTypes**. Thus, my hypothesis is that this issue might be associated with one of the dependencies in my project.

Below is a list of the dependencies currently utilized:

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
"@react-native-community/cli": "^11.3.3",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^18.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^18.1.0",
"@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.6",
"deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
"hermes-engine": "^0.11.0",
"jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"lottie-ios": "^3.5.0",
"lottie-react-native": "^5.1.6",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"patch-package": "^7.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.71.0",
"react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.2.2",
"react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
"react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
"react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
"react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
"react-native-keychain": "^8.1.1",
"react-native-localization": "^2.3.1",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
"react-native-navigation": "^7.32.1",
"react-native-sms-retriever": "^1.1.1",
"react-native-uuid-generator": "^6.1.1",
"react-native-webview": "^13.2.2",
"realm": "^11.10.1"
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or does anyone have insights on how to resolve this error? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards

In order to resolve this error, I plan to locate the offending dependency using a global search in the **node_modules** directory for **ViewPropTypes**.

I tried this solution to generate the diff files using **patch-package** and updated the node_modules as the below solution.

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702392/viewproptypes-will-be-removed-from-react-native-migrate-to-viewproptypes-export)

I'm expecting to remove this error.