# Deprecated 'ViewPropTypes' New Architecture React native

Tags: react-native

running the new architecture in react native https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/pillars-fabric-components
RTNCenteredText.ts file (the first part of code)

```
import type {ViewProps} from 'ViewPropTypes';
import type {HostComponent} from 'react-native';
import codegenNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';

export interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  text?: string;
}

export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
  'RTNCenteredText') as HostComponent<NativeProps>;
```

that's the error `The module 'ViewPropTypes' or its corresponding type declarations could not be found`
searching online `ViewPropTypes` is deprecated also if is the new architecture. what's the substitute of it

the file is in another directory of the app as the guide could it be this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the packages in your project, especially the ones that depend on ViewPropTypes, such as native-base, react-native-modal, react-native-snap-carousel, etc.

To see example,

- [ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to
  ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702392/viewproptypes-will-be-removed-from-react-native-migrate-to-viewproptypes-export)
- [[Fix] ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to
  ViewPropTypes exported from ‘deprecated-react-native-prop-types](https://networkcult.com/fix-viewproptypes-will-be-removed-from-react-native-migrate-to-viewproptypes-exported-from-deprecated-react-native-prop-types-3551/)

Comment: i already see this posts but if i delete my. project and create a new one i have to do all the step again and it's not pretty good there isn't a way to do it permanently ?

Comment: You don't have to delete your project and create a new one to update your packages. You can just run the commands in your existing project folder and it will update your package.json file and node_modules folder accordingly. You can also use version control tools like Git to keep track of the changes and revert them if needed. There is no permanent way to update your packages, as new versions are released frequently and you might want to choose which ones to use depending on your app's requirements and compatibility.